# countdown and prime number check

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write a function where if a person plugs in a value, it does a countdown to 0 and it shows if each number is prime.

```
def pn(n):
     while n > 0:
         #print (n)
         if n == 1:
             print '1 is a special number'
         elif n == 2:
             print '2 is EVEN and PRIME number'
         else:
             v_rem = n%2
             v_half = int(n/2)

             if v_rem == 0:
                 print n, ' is EVEN number'
             elif v_rem == 1:
                 print n, ' is ODD number'
                 i = 2
                 v_is_prime = "y"

                 while i <= v_half:
                     v_prim_rem=n%i
                     if v_prim_rem == 0:
                        print n, ' is not a prime number'
                        v_is_prime = "n"
                        break
                     i = i + 1
                     if v_is_prime == "y":
                         print n, 'is a prime number'
         n = n-1
```

Comment: Please indent the code correctly, since it determines the program's flow in Python. On the other hand, you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your concerns are related to the incorrect output:

```
10  is EVEN number
9  is ODD number
9 is a prime number # here
9  is not a prime number
8  is EVEN number
7  is ODD number
7 is a prime number
7 is a prime number # and here
6  is EVEN number
5  is ODD number
5 is a prime number
4  is EVEN number
3  is ODD number
2 is EVEN and PRIME number
1 is a special number
```

Your indentation is wrong: the check for `v_is_prime` should be *outside* the loop over `v_half`, and thus should be dedented one step:

```
v_is_prime = "y"
while i <= v_half:
    v_prim_rem=n%i
    if v_prim_rem == 0:
        print n, ' is not a prime number'
        v_is_prime = "n"
        break
    i = i + 1
if v_is_prime == "y":
    print n, 'is a prime number'
```

Alternatively, you can use `else` to handle this and get rid of the flag (which should really be booleans `True` and `False` not strings `'y'` and `'n'` if you do keep it):

```
while i <= v_half:
    if v_n % i == 0:
        print n, ' is not a prime number'
        break
    i = i + 1
else: # i.e. didn't 'break'
    print n, 'is a prime number'
```

However, don't use a `while` loop when you could use a `for` loop:

```
for n in range(n, 0, -1):
     ...
```

and

```
for i in range(int(n/2)):
     ...
else:
    ...
```

You could also adopt string formatting:

```
print "{0} is a prime number".format(n)
```

Finally, this problem is perfectly suited to the [Sieve of Erastosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes):

```
def pn(n):
    primes = range(n+1)
    primes[1] = 0
    for p in primes:
        if p > 0:
            for x in range(p, (n // p) + 1):
                try:
                    primes[x*p] = 0
                except IndexError:
                    break
    for x in range(n, 0, -1):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            print "{0} is EVEN".format(x)
        else:
            print "{0} is ODD".format(x)
        if primes[n] > 0:
            print "{0} is prime".format(x)
        else:
            print "{0} is not prime".format(x)
```